# on running server Cannot GET / error comes out

Tags: node.js

when i am runnning server cannot get displayed

```
/// Module dependencies.
var application_root = __dirname,
    express = require("express"), //Web framework
    path = require("path"), //Utilities for dealing with file paths
    mongoose = require('mongoose'); //MongoDB integration

//Create server
var app = express.createServer();

// Configure server
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.bodyParser()); //parses request body and populates req.body
    app.use(express.methodOverride()); //checks req.body for HTTP method overrides
    app.use(app.router); //perform route lookup based on url and HTTP method
    app.use(express.static(path.join(application_root, "public"))); //Where to serve static content
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions:true, showStack:true })); //Show all errors in development
});

//Start server
app.listen(4711, function () {
    console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

Comment: what do you want to get? describe what you want to achieve and why it fails

Comment: i just wanna run my index on server http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals here is link and look topic Create a simple web server

Comment: @user2887764 it looks like you aren't specifying a route for `/`. If you are getting a 404 error, this is probably why.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a index.html inside public to serve the site url. Also if you use routes(app.router) before static. Make sure it does not use '/' route. Which ever comes first you will see that one.

Answer (score 0):

First create a folder called `public` and then inside create a file called `index.html`.

And your last part should looks something like this:

```
//Start server
let listener = app.listen(4711, function () {
        console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", listener.address().port, app.settings.env);

});
```

Otherwise you get an error that `app.address().port` is `undefined`.